# How to implement checkbox in swift?

Tags: swift, checkbox

I am using this code for implementing checkbox but it is not working. Can anyone tell where I went wrong?

```
@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    if (checkBox.isSelected == false){

            checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_radio_selected"), for: .normal)
            checkBox.isSelected = true;


        } else {
            checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_radio_unselected"), for: .normal)
            checkBox.isSelected = false;
        }
```

Comment: What's happening? Is the method called? Is the same `if` test always the same one?

Comment: The method is not called.

Comment: And where did you expect it to be called? Did you connect a `IBOutlet`? Added by code a `addTarget`? How is linked the method and the button?

Comment: I have connected the IBOutlet and IBAction with the button. Want it to be called when I tap on the button.

Comment: And where is it? Is it a in a ViewController? Storyboard? UITableViewCell ? Etc. How did you instantiate the view? Do you have an IBOutlet `somebutton` then, in the viewDidLoad, or something like that, if you try to print it `print(someButton)`, does it work or crash? It's lacking information.

Comment: There was some problem with my ViewController. I deleted it, made new one and everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of doing this is to already assign the images for different `UIControl.State`. I don't know if you have created this button using `storyboard/xib` or have created it programatically. I would do it like this:

```
private let checkbox: UIButton = { 
  let button = UIButton()
  button.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_radio_selected"), for: .selected)
  button.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_radio_unselected"), for: .normal)

  return button
}()
```

Now, once your `IBAction` is called:

I am using this code for implementing checkbox but it is not working. Can anyone tell where I went wrong?

```
@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UIButton){

 checkBox.isSelected = sender.isSelected

 // Now you have already set the images according to control state. Once it is selected it will change the image and when it is not selected it will become normal and select the other image 
 }
```

Also, it will be best if you can create a Constants file and add these `named` strings there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the images for `normal`/`selected` states in the interface builder, or you can do it programmatically, e.g.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_radio_unselected"), for: .normal)
    checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle_radio_selected"), for: .selected)
}
```

Then your tap function can easily toggle the button state.

```
@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    checkBox.isSelected.toggle()
}
```